# Multiple writers for different types in the same Spring Batch step

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am writing a [Spring Batch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/) application with the following workflow:

1. Read some items of type `A` (using a `FlatFileItemReader<A>`).
2. Process an item, transforming it from `A` to `B`.
3. Write the processed items of type `B` (using a `JdbcBatchItemWriter<B>`)
4. Eventually, I should **call an external service** (a RESTful API, but it could be a `SimpleMailMessageItemWriter<A>`) **using data from the source type** `A`.

How can I configure such a workflow?

So far, I have found the following workaround:

- Configuring a `CompositeItemWriter<B>` which delegates to:

  1. The actual `ItemWriter<B>`
  2. A custom `ItemWriter<B>` implementation which converts `B` back to `A` and then writes an `A`

But this is a cumbersome solution because it forces me to either:

- Duplicate processing logic: from `A` to `B` and back again.
- Sneakily hide some attributes from the source object `A` inside `B`, polluting the domain model.

*Note*: since my custom item writer for `A` needs to invoke an external service, I would like to perform this operation after `B` has been successfully written.

Here are the relevant parts of the batch configuration code.

```
@Bean
public Step step(StepBuilderFactory steps, ItemReader<A> reader, ItemProcessor<A, B> processor, CompositeItemWriter<B> writer) {
    return steps.get("step")
            .<A, B>chunk(10)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public CompositeItemWriter<B> writer(JdbcBatchItemWriter<B> jdbcBatchItemWriter, CustomItemWriter<B, A> customItemWriter) {
    return new CompositeItemWriterBuilder<B>()
            .delegates(jdbcBatchItemWriter, customItemWriter)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your use case, I would encapsulate A and B in a wrapper type, such AB:

```
class AB {
   private A originalItem;
   private B transformedItem;
}
```

With that, you would have: `ItemReader<A>`, `ItemProcessor<A, AB>` and `ItemWriter<AB>`. The processor creates instances of AB in which it keeps a reference to the original item. The writer can then get access to both types and delegate to the `JdbcBatchItemReader<B>` and `SimpleMailMessageItemWriter<A>` as needed, something like:

```
class ABItemWriter implements ItemWriter<AB> {
    private JdbcBatchItemWriter<B> jdbcBatchItemWriter;
    private SimpleMailMessageItemWriter mailMessageItemWriter;
    // constructor with delegates

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends AB> items) throws Exception {
        jdbcBatchItemWriter.write(getBs(items));
        mailMessageItemWriter.write(getAs(items)); // this would not be called if the jdbc writer fails
    }
}
```

The methods `getAs` and `getBs` would extract items of type A/B from AB. Encapsulation for the win! BTW, a Java record is a good option for type AB.

Comment: Let us think if `mailMessageItemWriter` has another datasource than `jdbcBatchItemWriter`. When exception accoured one of it, will both rollback?

Comment: @Kaepxer, yes, assuming the step is driven by a JTA transaction manager that coordinates the transaction managers of both data sources. It is "all-or-nothing" semantics, as there will be a single transaction for all writers.